# Wordpress - Dynamic Content In Page

Tags: mysql, wordpress

So, I can edit a template file to echo out database information for logged in users (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/working-custom-database-tables-wordpress/) by creating a new page which has that template chosen.

I have a page with content and this contains a div (id="database"). I would like to echo out some of the database content into the selected div. I use this in the template file to do this after the main page content:

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in())
{
    global $wpdb;
    $customers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wps6_comments;");
    print_r($customers);
}
?>
```

What I'm not sure about - is how to insert this content into the page content itself (i.e. the Wordpress content) rather than after it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the WP Loop. Nice.

The problem you are encountering is that you need to set the context for the post. (Side not. Don't use $wpdb... Its not good practice to write SQL statements in files like that. Alas, you did so i'll use it in my example).

```
<?php
// Setup and Query
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
// Iterate through
foreach($result as $post):
  // Set Post Context
  setup_postdata($post);?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li><?php
wp_reset_postdata();
endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

I believe that is what you are looking for. Be advised, I haven't used vanilla php templates in a while and I have to run, so there is bound to be syntax errors in that.

Here is some documentation links: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata
And some theory:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I'm not sure I understand. I have some page content - and I would like to insert some wordpress database table information into that, in a specified place - have I misunderstood?